# Scrapy dowload zip file from ASP.NET site

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I need some help getting scrapy to download a file from an asp.net site. Normally from a browser one would click the link and the file would begin downloading, but that is not possible with scrapy so what I am trying to do is the following:

```
def retrieve(self, response):
        print('Response URL: {}'.format(response.url))

        pattern = re.compile('(dg[^\']*)')

        for file in response.xpath('//table[@id="dgFile"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'):
            file_url = file.xpath('@href').extract_first()

            target = re.search(pattern, file_url).group(1)
            viewstate = response.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract_first()
            viewstategenerator = response.xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]').extract_first()
            eventvalidation = response.xpath('//*[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').extract_first()

            data = {
                '_EVENTTARGET': target,
                '_VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
                '_VIEWSTATEGEERATOR': viewstategenerator,
                '_EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation
            }

            yield FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formdata=data,
                callback=self.end(response)
            )
```

I am trying to submit the information to the page in order the receive the zip file back as a response, however this is not working as I hoped it would. Instead I am simply getting the same page as a response.

In a situation like this is it even possible to use scrapy to download this file? does anyone have any pointers?

I have also tried to use Selenium+PhantomJS but I run into a dead end trying to transfer the session from scrapy to selenium. I would be willing to use selenium for this one function but I need to use scrapy for this project.

Comment: Have you tried using the Files Pipeline? [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#topics-media-pipeline-enabling)

Comment: I have used Files Pipeline before to download files but in those cases it had been using direct links to the files, in this case I do not understand how to do so because the link looks like this: `javascript:__doPostBack('dgFile$ctl03$Download','')` and when you click that link in a browser it performs a POST using the parameters that are in the code I posted.

Comment: I mean, where does the `javascript:__doPostBack('dgFile$ctl03$Download','')` take you to? If you sent a scrapy post request to that link, you can download the file.

Comment: The link makes a post request to the current page which then downloads the file. I should mention that the file is auto-generated based on a previous request made by me so even if the there was a unique URL for this file it would not be static.

Comment: You can try [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash), which can execute javascript to click the link.  Once the generated URL comes back, you can retrieve it with a Files Pipeline.